# How to Google Maps marker blink for time interval?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, blink

I am new at Google Maps technologies.I want to blink or bounce google maps marker for a time interval for example one minute.Is it possible to do it? Could you please show me a way to succeed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may cause errors. (using googlemap without apikey)

```js
var on = true;
var intervalSeconds = 0.5;
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatLng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});

setInterval(function() {
   if(on) {
     marker.setMap(null);
   } else {
     marker.setMap(map);
   }
  on = !on;
}, intervalSeconds * 1000);
```

```css
#map {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.This helps me to provide blink effect.

Answer (score 6):

The `google.maps.Marker` class supports `setAnimation(animation:Animation)` method, which according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Animation):

> Start an animation. Any ongoing animation will be cancelled. Currently
>   supported animations are: BOUNCE, DROP. Passing in null will cause any
>   animation to stop.

So you can just call

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

to start bouncing animation and

```
marker.setAnimation(null);
```

to stop it. Working example:

```js
function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
  
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false"});
</script>
<body onload="initMap();" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
 <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Blinking animation is not supported out of the box, but you can create it yourself, the example is already included in other answers.

Comment: No problem. If you think the answer is helpful you can upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my new stackoverflow account and my reputation is less than 15 to upvote anyone :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for blinking maps marker you can use .gif file since google maps marker does not support blinking animation.

Just change the source of your image to .gif file and it will work.
for example.

```
var mapIcon= "/assets/mapIcon.gif");  
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    icon: mapIcon,
    optimized: false
  });
```

[NOTE] Don't forget to add `optimized: false` because sometimes it will not work properly.